# What would be the most efficient/clean way to deeply sort a multidimensional list in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting, multidimensional-array

Example:
From this list:

```
list = [[10, 9, 1], [2, 1, 1,], [4, 11, 16]]
```

I'd like to have:

```
print list
[[1, 1, 1], [2, 4, 9], [10, 11, 16]]
```

Is it possible with the *list.sort()* function or do I have to write a custom loop ?

Comment: Are you sure what you want is `[[1, 1, 1], [2, 4, 9], [10, 11, 16]]` and not `[[2, 1, 1], [4, 11, 16], [10, 9, 1]]` as Max suggest?

Comment: ups )) I totally misunderstood the question. voted to delete my answer.

Comment: Yes, I'd like to sort the values, not the nested lists.

Comment: It's pretty unlikely you'll find something in the standard library to do this, since it requires exchanging values between data structures – doing this in a general way would be very involving. The most efficient way would be writing a custom quicksort that will work with a 2-dimensional index. The cleanest way would be flattening the list, sorting that, and then rebuilding the nested lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of flattening, sorting, then rebuilding the nested lists, as @Inerdia suggested in the comments above.

I've tried to use generators and iterators where possible, but I'm sure there are cleverer, more efficient ways of getting the result!

```
from itertools import izip

l = [[10, 9, 1], [2, 1, 1,], [4, 11, 16]]
# flatten the list and sort it
f = sorted(inner for outer in l for inner in outer)
# group it into 3s again using izip
new_list = [list(l) for l in izip(*[iter(f)]*3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> l = [[10, 9, 1], [2, 1, 1,], [4, 11, 16]]
>>> L = sorted([sub[i] for sub in l for i in range(3)])
>>> print L
[1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 9, 10, 11, 16]
```

Now you can group `L` in groups of 3

Comment: I think you mean L = sorted([sub[i] for sub in l for i in range(3)])
Thanks, that will do the trick I guess